# How to rephrase "cream flavoured cream"?

Tags: word-choice, nouns, synonyms

I saw this on my wafers the other day: "Wafers with **cream** flavoured **cream**". This sounds horribly recursive to my ear. How can you rephrase it or use a synonym without losing the original meaning?

Comment: What’s the “original” meaning?

Comment: This bugged me, too. Although the version I saw was probably more a translation issue.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Makers of mass-produced dessert snacks in the United States struggled with this problem for years, a problem exacerbated in their case by the fact that the "cream-flavored cream" filling might in fact contain no cream. Their solution was to popularize terms such as "creme" and "creme-filled"—without the grave accent over the first *e*—and the even more heavily processed-sounding "kreme" and "kreme-filled."  Dunkin' Donuts, for example, currently offers a Vanilla Kreme Filled Donut and a Boston Kreme Donut whose debt to any living cow (or kow) is unknown to me. A marketer might confidently claim that a wafer contained "cream-flavoured creme," without having to go into detail (on the front of the package, anyway) about what industrial substances made up the creme.

If you wanted to stay away from *creme* and *kreme*, the simplest way to avoid the repetition of *cream* in your example would be to replace the second *cream* with *filling*: "Wafers with cream-flavoured filling." In the context of a mass-produced sweet treat, U.S. readers would immediately interpret "filling" to mean "squishy or pasty (and very sugary) partially hydrogenated goo." But I don't know whether *filling* carries the same instantly recognizable sense outside the U.S. that it does here.

Comment: I often wondered about "kreme" and "creme" and now I know. Thank you!

Comment: I thought "crème" was just the French word for "cream", and they used the French spelling to seem fancier (dropping the accent because Americans don't like letters they can't easily type on a standard US keyboard).

Comment: It feels like "creme" is used more as a contraction of _crème pâtissière_ than a straight synonym for cream

Comment: @Mari-LouA *Kreme* is like how you sometimes see things made with “artificial crab”, which is actually [*surimi*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surimi), labelled as being made of *krab*.  The *c*-to-*k* swap is a “faked” meme,  with the mnemonic connection to the *k* in *fake*. There may be some legal niceties about truth in advertising at work here, since in many jurisdictions you cannot pretend something has that thing in it by putting the thing in its name if does not actually have it. However, ***Grape Nuts* cereal** was specifically exempted from this regulation despite having neither.

Comment: In the UK, I wouldn't necessarily expect a filling to be a "squishy or pasty (and very sugary) partially hydrogenated goo." But I'd expect a cream-flavoured filling to have a sort-of-creamy texture, which would fit that description. So "cream-flavoured filling" would make me imagine the right substance.

Answer (score 10):

***Cream*** has multiple meanings in cookery, and especially in baking and confectionery.

Besides being literally the thick fat that rises to the top of milk, it’s also used for other similarly-textured pastes and fillings, especially ones which were originally mostly cream-based but whose composition shifted over the years according to fashion and taste.  This isn’t just modern commercial euphemism: it’s happened for centuries.  For instance, [violet creams](http://www.charbonnel.co.uk/products/english-rose-amp-violets.html) are chocolates filled with a paste of sugar, cream, and violet extract, while [custard creams](http://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/custard_creams_54317) are a biscuit whose filling consists just of sugar mixed into butter or margarine.

So two different meanings of *cream* are involved for your wafers: they are filled with cream [in the sense of a sugary paste] that has been flavoured with cream [in the sense of milk fat]. (Or, perhaps more likely, flavoured with synthetic cream [sense of milkfat] flavour.)

Depending on the specific filling used, a less redundant wording might be something like *cream-flavoured fondant*, *cream-flavoured ganache*, or simply *cream-flavoured filling* if no more specific culinary term fits the bill.