# The Difference Between "Cream" and "Creme"

Tags: meaning, grammar, terminology

I've always wondered whether to use cream or creme. I know, both are used, but when and how? From my understanding, I think of creme as a dessert.

> She pressed down on the lever to shoot out a mound of whipped creme.

Though, I don't know about the cream. Multiple times, I've had people come up to me and say, "It's c-r-e-a-m, not c-r-e-m-e, when I'm talking about whipped creme. Then again, I'm 12.

The point is, does creme have multiple uses? So far, I only think of the dessert as that.

Comment: *creme* is the Anglicized French spelling.  *cream* is the English spelling.  It depends on the audience and the effect you’re going for.

Comment: If you want to be really Frenchy, you use the spelling *crème* (example: [Squirrel Brand Crème Caramel Pecans](https://www.amazon.com/Squirrel-Brand-Caramel-Pecans-18-Ounce/dp/B004W1HDMQ)) Note: in French, this is pronounced as "kghem", not "kreem".

Comment: @sumelic - I’d still put an ’r’ in there: “kghrem”

Comment: @Jim: Well, it's a sound that doesn't exist in English, so there is no perfect way to write it. In the International Phonetic Alphabet it would be written as [ʁ] or [χ].

Comment: @sumelic - I agree there’s no perfect way to write it without IPA but the ’r’ does contribute a sound in that word even if it’s not the sound we Americans might propose. At least for me I think it’s  closer with the ’r’ than without it.

Comment: In the US there's a legal distinction.  "Cream", with a few exceptions, can only be used if the thing being described contains dairy cream.  "Creme" is used for other cases.  The two are pronounced the same (though the accented "crème" is generally pronounced Frency-style).

Comment: I agree with @Hot Licks—if you use genuine heavy cream and whip it up, that's *whipped cream*; if you call it *whipped creme* I would assume it was some sort of non-dairy or semi-dairy substitute. I think this might actually be why you have a sense that desserts get the *creme* spelling: things like that yummy Oreo frosting are called "*creme* filling" specifically because they're not made with actual cream, even though they have a "creamy" consistency. (There's also crème fraîche, which is a whole other thing. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cr%C3%A8me_fra%C3%AEche)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. @1006a thanks for the clarification on what to use  "creme" for. I'm thinking another example for that could be the filling in twinkies or such. I'm guessing creme is just an artificial type ingredient in English?

Comment: but couple it with another French word and it’s the real deal: creme anglaise, creme fraiche, creme brulee...

Comment: Exactly. Thought of as a delicacy in France, but here, junk food we shouldn't be eating.

Comment: @AniCrosby - It's all a matter of moderation.  The French have some very heavy foods but they eat them in moderation, along with a very large variety of other foods.

Comment: For more on _creme_ as artificial cream, see "[How to rephrase 'cream-flavoured cream'](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/119505/how-to-rephrase-cream-flavoured-cream/119513).

Comment: @1006a And if it's too artificial to even be labelled _creme_, it's _kreme_. And probably krispy, too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to rephrase "cream flavoured cream"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/119505/how-to-rephrase-cream-flavoured-cream)

Comment: If you are concerned about unnecessary variants to standard English and aspire to join la crème de la crème, I’d start by dropping “multiple” in favour of “many”.

Answer (score 4):

The first two definitions of "creme" on Merriam-Webster are:

> 1
>   :  a sweet liqueur
>
> 2
>   :  cream or a preparation made with or resembling cream used in cooking

The word comes from French crème, which means...*cream!*  Cream, in English, is a word that means "that dairy product that comes from the fatty stuff from milk."  Cream is used in common foods like whipped cream and sour cream.  Creme, on the other hand, does *not* refer to what we in English call cream.  It is used in English only in many culinary terms--which come from French--such as crème brûlée, and in expressions like "crème de la crème."

So the people telling you that it's whipped cream, not whipped creme, were correct.

Comment: In British English "creme" would be pronounced differently (as crème with a short vowel) from "cream".

Answer (score 0):

*Cream* is much better than *creme*.  I think *creme* originated for advertising.  It makes me think of creme rinse (hair conditioner).

If you want to use a French term, then you may use *crème*.  For example, this site is the crème de la crème of Q&A sites.

**Edit**:

Sorry, I forgot to say that if it's whipped, it's definitely *cream*.

Comment: I'd disagree, *cr*(è/e)*me* makes me think if crème brûlée and fancy French food (with lots of diacritics of course) while *cream* makes me think of a stodgier British cream. So, at least to me and perhaps to other Brits, crème is much better than cream.

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey  Let's hear it for Cornish clotted cream.

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey - I'm sorry I wasn't clear.  I was trying to say that *cream* is better than *creme*.  I didn't mean to say it was better than *crème*.  *Crème* is *definitely* the crème de la crème.

Comment: Well, in that case, I'd just about agree with you, in Britain, you tend not to find too many *creme*s but those that you do wouldn't be as nice as the *crème*s or probably the *cream*s

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey But we don't normally use *crème* in Britain, unless it is part of the name of a dish that is otherwise written in French, such as *crème brûlée*, or *crème caramel*. In posh restaurants the soups are sometimes shown on the menu as *crème de tomates* etc. Where cream is employed in a dish of English origin, we would write *cream*, as in *cream sponge*, or quintessentially *cream teas*. *Crème Anglaise* is simply the French name for "custard". To put that on a British menu really would be pretentious.

Comment: @WS2 Yes, I agree, the English word is used for English food while the French word is used for fancy food. I tend not to see many *creme*s and, if it is written like that, it just seems like they've missed out an accent.

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey I don't know what you mean by "fancy". Used in that way it is an American expression. In Britain *fancy* nearly always has to do with sex - *Nancy tickled me fancy*.

Comment: @WS2 - I think when I say *fancy* it's similar to you saying *posh*.  Btw, even in UK English I believe there are many non-sex-related uses of *fancy*, e.g. *Do you fancy a cup of tea?*  // Personally I would recommend just eliminating *creme* (sans accent) from one's vocabulary.  Nowadays, you don't even have to say *creme rinse* -- you can say *conditioner*.

Comment: Can the downvoter please say what he doesn't like about this answer?

Comment: @aparente001 Yes I may have exaggerated there. There is also *fancy dress*, which Americans don't use. They talk about a *costume party* rather than *fancy-dress* party. But there is a particular American use of *fancy* which is seldom employed in Britain. I believe they use it much as we would *posh*. Problem they have is that there is not supposed to be any such thing as social class (ha, ha) in America, which rather prohibits words like *posh*.

Comment: @WS2 - I agree that your *posh* = my *fancy*.  I have to disagree with your last sentence, though.

Comment: @aparente001 My apologies if I caused offence. The wording of my comment perhaps indicates that I had overlooked that you were American. But my experience has often been that discussions about social class makes some of your compatriots distinctly uncomfortable. However I have also noticed that in recent years that the term "working class" has become more acceptable in an American context. But perhaps this discussion belongs on a different site e.g. History.

Comment: @WS2 - No offense taken!  Well, I guess you know some pretty touch North Americans.  It must be a minefield, trying to converse with them.

Answer (score 0):

Cream has has a specific medical meaning, relating to a topical dosage form of a drug:

An emulsion, semisolid  dosage form, usually containing >20% water and volatiles and/or <50% hydrocarbons, waxes, or polyols as the vehicle. This dosage form is generally for external application to the skin or mucous membranes.